# Сохранение списка со списками в csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Имеется список, состоящий из следующих списков:

['Профиль участника Mostafa', 'site1/1', 'Веб-сайт', 'site2', 'Twitter', 'sdfsdf', 'WeChat'] ['Профиль участника Dinesh', 'site1/2', 'Twitter', '45fghfgh', 'День рождения', '28 октября'] ['Профиль участника Roman', 'site1/3', 'Twitter', 'drgedrg', 'День рождения', '9 февраля']

Элементы под четными индексами во вложенных списках являются заголовками столбцов. Нужно сохранить данные в CSV в таком виде:

Профиль участника  Веб-сайт   Twitter     WeChat   День рождения
site1/3             site2     sdfsdf      пусто      пусто
site1/2              пусто    45fghfgh    пусто      28 октября
site1/3              пусто    drgedrg     пусто      9 февраля

То есть, мы считываем заголовки таблицы путем их поиска в списках. После этого формируем таблицу. В ней на каждой строке находится информация о пользователе.

Как это сделать?

Comment: А вот эти списки - это исходные данные, или вы их откуда-то парсили? А то может проще будет перепарсить по-нормальному? Потому что  таком виде - это куча мусора, а не исходные данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, как-то так это можно сделать:

```
data = [
    ['Профиль участника Mostafa', 'site1/1', 'Веб-сайт', 'site2', 'Twitter', 'sdfsdf', 'WeChat'],
    ['Профиль участника Dinesh', 'site1/2', 'Twitter', '45fghfgh', 'День рождения', '28 октября'],
    ['Профиль участника Roman', 'site1/3', 'Twitter', 'drgedrg', 'День рождения', '9 февраля']
]

rows = []
for line in data:
    item = {
        'Профиль участника': line[1],
    }
    for n in range(2, len(line)-1, 2):
        item[line[n]] = line[n+1]
    rows.append(item)

import csv

keys = ['Профиль участника', 'Веб-сайт', 'Twitter', 'WeChat', 'День рождения']
with open('result.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Благодарю. работает. Только дополнил строку: dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, delimiter=';') - добавил разделитель ";", чтобы все писалось не в один столбец, а в разные.